# Passing values from another form Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

All the tutorial in passing forms in the web are all from form1 then open form2 and then pass the value.

I want something reverse. form1 and form 2 is open so if you click ok in form2 the value you get in form 2 will be passed in form 1.

ex. form1 click buttton openform2button (form 2 shows) write 7 (number 7) on a textBox (in form2) click button okbutton then form 2 closes after form2 closes the textbox in form1 will store the data in form2. so the 7 you will put in textbox form2 will be saved and transferred in textbox form1. is that possible?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17371/Passing-Data-between-Windows-Forms check this

Comment: Please try to forget your code, clean up your mind, read your question again. Is it easy to follow?

Comment: How does a TextBox pass its text to code in a form?  Same answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of ways you could do it:

- Share a model object between form1 and form2.
- Have form2 expose an event that form1 subscribes to. Pass the values in the event args.
- Have form2 expose the value as a public property that form1 reads after form2 closes.

Comment: Good answer. The option about sharing a common model is the most generic. It can be implemented in a number of ways. If we reduce the model to one value and keep this model in a public property of one of the forms we arrive at option three. Option two will work too, but logistics of subscribing/un-subscribing may become unneeded overhead.

Comment: is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Exposing a property is probably the cleanest way.  If you really want to, I'm sure you can have a class with a static property that can be set by the forms, but that code is not as reuseable.

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a public property on Form2 that Form1 will access when it needs to see the value. Something like this:

```
using(Form2 form2 = new Form2()) 
{
  if(form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
  {
    form1Logger(form2.NumberWritten);
  }
}
```

The property can be something as simple as this:

```
class Form2
{
     public String NumberWritten 
     {
         get{return textBox.Value;}
     }
}
```

Comment: Sir, is this working how can I make it work?

Comment: I updated my code so that it can work now.