# How to transfer data from one form to another in winforms c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server-2008

1. I want to create at 5-6 forms in windows application to insert data.
2. Each form contain at-least 15-20 Controls. All Forms Belongs to
       different table. But some with same.
3. I have to created stored "Next"named button on each form, such that
   when i click on next button all the information filled on that button get store some where
   and in this way after storing the information on the last button where a Submit button is
   dragged, on clicking on that submit button all the data got saved into the data base.
4. Please tell me how can i store the data inserted on previous forms and call it on click event of submit button.

For now i am having all the controls on the same page and i have used these codes for insertion.

```
 private void submit_addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //personal data insert
                Personal per = new Personal();
                per.Name = nametxt.Text;
                per.FatherName = f_nametxt.Text;
                per.MotherName = m_nametxt.Text;
                per.Gotra = gotra_txt.Text;
                per.Panth = panthcb.Text;
                per.FamilyHead = fhntext.Text;
                per.Educationlvl = edulvlcb.Text;
                per.Education = educb.Text;
                per.Blood = bloodcb.Text;
                per.Gender = genderlist.Text;
                per.Marrital = MarritalStatus;
                per.DateOfBirth = dobdtp.Text;
                if (new InsertAction().Insertpersonal(per))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Personal Insertion Happen ");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Personal Insertion does not Happen ");
                }

                // spouse data insert
                Spouse sps = new Spouse();
                sps.Spousename = s_nametxt.Text;
                sps.Spouseeducationlvl = s_edulvlcb.Text;
                sps.Spouseeducation = s_educb.Text;
                sps.Spouseblood = s_bgcb.Text;
                sps.Spousedob = s_dobdtp.Text;
                if (new InsertAction().Insertspouse(sps))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Spouse Insertion Happen ");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Spouse Insertion does not Happen ");
                }

                // Resident data insert
                Ressident resi = new Ressident();
                resi.RessiHnumber = ressi_numtxt.Text;
                resi.RessihCmplx = ressi_complextxt.Text;
                resi.RessiStrt = ressi_streettxt.Text;
                resi.RessiLandmrk = ressi_landtxt.Text;
                resi.RessiArea = ressi_areatxt.Text;
                resi.RessiCity = ressi_citytxt.Text;
                resi.RessiPhone = Convert.ToInt64(ressi_phnotxt.Text);
                resi.RessiMobile = Convert.ToInt64(mobi_notxt.Text);
                if (new InsertAction().Insertressident(resi))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Ressident Insertion Happen ");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Ressident Insertion does not Happen ");
                }
                //occupation data insert
                Occupation ocp = new Occupation();
                ocp.Occuptype = occup_typetxt.Text;
                ocp.Occupadd = office_addresstxt.Text;
                ocp.Occupnature = occup_naturecb.Text;
                ocp.Occupphone = Convert.ToInt64(office_phno1txt.Text);
                ocp.Occupmobile = Convert.ToInt64(office_mobnotxt.Text);
                if (new InsertAction().Insertoccupation(ocp))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Occupation Insertion Happen ");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Occupation Insertion does not Happen ");
                }


            }
```

Please Help me.
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing values from another form Winforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073267/passing-values-from-another-form-winforms)

Comment: You can also create 5-6 ClassObjects related to your forms (one class for every form) and with public definitions (set; get;) also related to every object on every Form.After every "Next" clicking, you can keep all properties about that forms in it's classObject.I hope this help you

Answer (score 4):

For sending values between two forms, you may

1-> Send the values in the constructor of the second form. You may create a paramterized constructor and send the values when you initialize the form as :

```
 Form1 obj = new Form1(Object);
```

2-> You may take a reference in to your first form in the second form.

In second form,

```
public Form1 objForm1;
```

and in First Form,

```
Form2 objForm2=new Form2();
Form2.objForm1=this;
```

and then you can use Form2's objForm1 to refer to Form1's textbox or any control.

**EDIT :**

Consider you want to send all values from `Form1` to `Form2`

In your second form you must have a variable of type Form1 that refers to the prev form. So in second form,

```
public Form1 objForm1;
```

and then you need to send the current instance of the `Form1` to `Form2` as

```
Form2 objForm2=new Form2();
Form2.objForm1=this;
```

i.e. the objForm1 that you created in Form2 refers to this instance of Form1.

Now in Form2 you may use any of Form1's control or variable as,

`Form1.TextBox1` or `Form1.Variable`

Comment: Hey please tell me exactly that what should i do on form 1 then on second than on third. please post at-least 2-3 line code for each form so that it get more clear to me.. please

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/thiagu304/passdata05172006234318PM/passdata.aspx

Comment: I had go through it bt it is the case when we have to pass only on value bt what to do in case of multiple values

Comment: Form2.objForm1=this; is showing error i have written this code on class level

Comment: it is saying that  
Form2.objForm1=this;  is a field but used as type and invalid token '='

Comment: write it before you want to show Form2, in some function or on some button click and not on class level.

Comment: preferebly while submitting form1 or while navigating from form1 to form2 as it holds the current instance values.