# Accessing a textbox value from form1 in form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox on form1. 
What I want to do is to get the value of the textbox from form1 into form2. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was create a new project and add a second form then added a textbox to both forms, with a button on Form1 to push the value of its text box to Form2.

To achieve this, create a Property on Form2 and set it from Form1. Like this:

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 frm2;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Show(this);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm2.ModifyTextBoxValue = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string ModifyTextBoxValue
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

Done this way, the same property can also be used to pull data *from* Form2 if desired.

Comment: why there is error on textbox1.Text when I add the public string ModifyTextBoxValue?

Comment: @user1647667 What error are you getting, the above code works correctly

Comment: textBox1.Text does not exist in the current context. I just add textbox on the form2 that contains the same property name for the textbox. and same textbox property name in form1 @Mark Hall

Comment: @user1647667 Make sure you use the Property as written with the name of your TextBox in place of the TextBox that I used(TextBox1). All I did was create a new project and add a second form then added a textbox to both of them.  What is the names of your Form1 and Form2 textbox, I will alter code to use them

Answer (score 0):

you could use the .Tag property (look at my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468241/how-to-apply-more-than-one-tag-property-in-c)
the simple way to do it is like this:
add another textBox in form2

do this in the form1. this code will store the texBox.text in form1

```
try
{
    private void change_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         form1 frm1 = new form();
         frm1.Tag = this.textBox1.text;
         frm1.ShowDialog();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

then write this when you load your form2. this code will replace texBox2 value with the value of texBox1

```
string myText = (string)this.Tag;
   this.textBox2.text = myText;
```