# Passing Data form two different forms

Tags: c#, winforms

My objective is to be able to enter a value in the textbox in form1 then press enter (when pressing the enter button the value will be pass to a method called setvalue. When the switch button is pressed then the form one will hide and open form2. Form2 has two buttons, show and exit. When show is clicked i need to display a messagebox that display the data in textbox in form1 by calling the getvalue method.

Please I'm open for ideas.

This is form one

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int secretValue;

    public  void SetValue (int value){
          secretValue = value;
    }
    public int GetValue ()
    {

       return secretValue;
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.Visible = true;
        this.Hide();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        secretValue = Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text);
        SetValue(secretValue);
    }
}
```

this form two

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
           int val = frm1.GetValue();


           MessageBox.Show(string.Format(val.ToString(), "My Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK));
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you can just pass the data to form 2 by a constructor parameter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing data between two forms using properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087934/passing-data-between-two-forms-using-properties)

Comment: This question has been asked many times before - did you search StackOverflow or check the suggested links before asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor value on your form 2. It should look like this:

```
public Form2(int secValue)
```

Then you can call it on your form 1 by passing the value

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(secretValue);
```

Maybe you can assign it to a global variable in your form 2, so that it can be referenced by your code in all of the form. Your form two can now be:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    int passedValue = 0;

    public Form2(int secValue)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        passedValue = secValue;
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           MessageBox.Show(string.Format(passedValue.ToString(), "My Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK));
    }
}
```

In my opinion, there's no need for the property you created. Always remember, the values you assign to a class will be null if you change from form to form.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will not work becuase you are creating new instance of form1 and trying to get the value from there, It will only have the default vaue of int.

```
 private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        int val = frm1.GetValue();
    }
```

Simply what you can do is to have a `public property` defined within `Form2`. and set the value of this property before showing Form2,

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

    //settting the value to Form2's property SecrectValueOfForm2, Now this value is available within Form2
    frm2.SecrectValueOfForm2 = ValueInForm1;
    frm2.Visible = true;
    this.Hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz try code as shown below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private int secretValue;
   Form2 frm2 = new Form2();

public  void SetValue (int value){
      secretValue = value;
}
public int GetValue ()
{

   return secretValue;
}

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    frm2 .Show();
    this.Hide();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      frm2.Owner = this;
}

private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    secretValue = Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text);
    SetValue(secretValue);
}
}
```

And On Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}

private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
       int val = ((Form1 )this.Owner).GetValue();


       MessageBox.Show(string.Format(val.ToString(), "My Application", MessageBoxButtons.OK));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Form2

```
 public Int32 _txtval { get; set; }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(_txtval.ToString());
        }
```

Form1

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2._txtval = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            frm2.Visible = true;
            this.Hide();
  }
```