# C# Winform - parse data from Form2 to method in Form1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two Forms - Form1 and Form2.

Form2 contains textBox1 to enter data.

In Form1 I have a method that uses data from textBox1.

The question is: How do I parse data from textBox1 in Form2 to a method in Form1 ?

I've been trying to use constructors and delegates, but they do not work.

Thank you very much, cheers!

Comment: do you have an instance of Form2 in Form1?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186722/pass-a-value-from-one-form-to-another