# Pass the Value from a form and view in a DataGridView in another form using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms: ScienceHome and Eligibility.

- ScienceHome form has several ComboBoxes and textBoxes and a Button named "Check Eligibility"
- Eligibility form has a DataGridView to show the data, column-wise.

Now, when I will click on "Check Eligibility" button on ScienceHome form, I want the data from all the textBoxes and ComboBox pass into Eligibilty form and fill the DataGridView on it.

How can I do that?

**ScienceHome form screenshot:**

[image: ScienceHome form screenshot]

**Eligibity form screenshot:**

[image: Eligibity form screenshot]

Comment: Checking the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186722/pass-a-value-from-one-form-to-another) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886544/passing-a-value-from-one-form-to-another-form) would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Add an argument with the type of the form to the constructor of Eligibility:

```
public Eligibility(ScienceHome frm) {
    // Do whatever you want with frm
}
```

And then adjust your code, so you pass the argument:

```
Eligibility e = new Eligibility(this);
e.Show();
```

**EDIT:** As Vahid said, it's not good practice. You could also just put every field into the constructor like:

```
public Eligibility(string bangla, string english) { // Continue like this until you have all fields
    // Do whatever you want with the parameters
}
```

And then call the constructor like:

```
Eligibility e = new Eligibility(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text); // Continue until you have all fields
e.Show();
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to pass the forms' references, it's much better to just pass the needed data.

Comment: Brother, can you be more specific please?
I'm a very beginner,.So, it would be good to catch the concept if you tell me in which event should I write which part of the condition..
Never mind.

Comment: Yes, I need to just pass the value of some text box to another form, @ Vahid Naderi

Comment: I edited my post to pass on data only, like Vahid said

Comment: Hey Jean, can u please help me to generate the constructor of Eligibility?
As I mentioned, I'm a very beginner in C#.

Comment: Just collect all fields you need in the DataGridView, put them into the constructor as strings and pass the text box values as parameters, like I showed in my post.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for putting that into another answer, but I´m not allowed to comment...

Like Jean Luc said:

in your Eligibity form, just create the constructor eg.:

```
public Eligibity(String subject1, String subject2){
//use the Strings in your Eligibity form
}
```

and in your ScienceHome form, you call the constructor of Eligibity by doing so:

```
private void checkEligibility_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Eligibity eligibity = new Eligibity(textBox_Bangla.Text,textBox_English.Text);
}
```

checkEligibility_Click() is your buttons 'click'-event and by calling

```
new Eligibity(textBox_Bangla.Text,textBox_English.Text);
```

you are passing the parameters (your Subjects as Strings) to the constructor of your Eligibity form and use them there.