# Accessing components of another form

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

I have two `Forms` in my application. A `Form` has the following fields: `txtPower`, `txtTension` and `txtCurrent`. I would like to access the values ​​filled in these `TextBox` through another `Form`. In the second `Form` I instantiated an `object` of the first `Form` (MotorForm), however I do not have access to the `TextBox`.

```
public MacroForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MotorForm motorForm = new MotorForm();
    motorForm.Show();
}
```

Is there any way?

Comment: You have to change access modifiers of controls. Set `Modifier` property to `public`

Comment: pass them through the constructor

Comment: Possible duplicate [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20186722/pass-a-value-from-one-form-to-another) to know more

Comment: @apomene: This is a possibility if he does not want to read them, but he wrote *access the values*, which does not exclude read-access.

Answer (score 1):

*Please do not expose the controls in your form. Never. (Unless you have a really good reason.)*

If the problem is simple enough *not* to use MVVM (or the like) in your program (which you should consider for every program that's but trivial), you should expose the *values* of the instantiated form via properties. Think

```
public string Power
{
   get { return txtPower.Text; }
   set 
   { 
       if(ValidatePower(value))
       {
           txtPower.Text = value;
       }
       else
       {
           // throw ??
       }
    }
}
```

If we can make a sensible assumption about the type of the value we could extend this to

```
public double Power
{
    get
    {
        // parse the value
        // validate the value
        // throw if not valid ??
        // return the value
    }
    set
    {
        // validate the value
        // set the value in the text box
    }
}
```

If you exposed the `txtPower` object, you'd make the instantiating class depend on implementation details of the instantiated class, which is virtually *never* a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is a perfect situation for using `ShowDialog` for opening your form.

To accomplish this, you need to change the `Modifiers` property of the controls you want to access on `MotorForm` and set them to `Public`. And also set the `DialogResult` property of your form somewhere to a desired value i.e OK. Anyway the easier way to do this is to set it on the button that is supposed to close the form. Suppose OK or CANCEL buttons.

Then you can create your form this way:

```
MotorForm motorForm = new MotorForm();
if(motorForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     string myValue = motorForm.txtPower.Text; //you can access your values this way
}
```